# Greenish/Gray Mold on all beds and matresses

Tags: flooring, mold, humidity, ceramic-tile, condensation

I moved to a new apartment unit in the beginning of the year and then I went away for a 2 week trip and when I came back I noticed greenish dust on the the furniture. I google it and found out that it is a type of mold. I wiped down and I didn't pay that much attention. For a couple of weeks I noticed a strange smell , then I checked under my bed and saw that it is all greenish including the bottom of my mattress.
My city is in Northern Somalia average weather indoor temperature is around 86F and 85% humidity. I usually switch off the AC because of the high cost of electricity.

I first thought it may be some moisture coming from the floor beneath me which is a data center which is cooled 24x 7 at a low temperature but i couldn't see an floor condensation or sweat. Although some of my neighbors mentioned that in the summer when the temperature gets hot that floor gets sweaty.

I got few questions, would appreciate if anyone can provide their suggestions, as I am quite unfamiliar with the greenish mold and a google search didn't help much.

1. Is it safe to clean and wipe down the bed and mattress and reuse them or should I throw them away?
2. If I am forced to throw away the bed and the mattress? Is there any mold resistance bed or mattress I should be using in this type of weather? like maybe bed frame made of metal?
3. For health reasons is it safe to stay sleeping in the moldy bed and mattress for a couple of weeks until I get something else?
4. How can I control the growth of this mold? Running continuous AC may reduce the Humidity but that is a cost factor for me. I tried to run continuous ceiling fan but that didn't reduce the humidity.
5. underneath the bed it was never moped, could that be a main reason why mold grew on the bed and mattress?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Posts should contain only one clear question. Also, health questions and questions about furniture use are not home improvement per the definition on this site, so don't ask those here. Please revise to simplify and comply with these rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mold is primarily an inhalation hazard.  How bad the hazard is depends on a lot of factors.  Usually it is immuno-compromised, mold sensitive, pregnant, old or really young that have the largest health concerns.  There are a few types of mold that are really toxic but you'd need lab testing to determine what species you have.  If you feel terrible sleeping there then I'd be more prone to get rid of the moldy stuff than clean it.

In general mold grows everywhere, trees, leaves, dirt, etc.  The worst place to have it is in your bedroom since you spend a lot of time sleeping and breathing there.

If you clean your mattress you are probably ok at least for a while.  I'd just wear a N95 while cleaning it.  Kind of depends what it looks like before and how long it takes to clean.  Bleach and white vinegar work to clean for mold - choose one or the other don't mix.

86F and 85% RH means there is a lot of moisture in the air.  Generally you don't want RH over 60% or fungus, mold, and dust mites all grow.  Instead of a/c while you are away I'd run a dehumidifier with an auto drain to pull the moisture levels down.

Mold also tends to grow where the air is stagnant so especially for your bedroom I'd put a fan that just blows air under the bed or prop the mattress up to encourage air circulation while I was away.

You can get outdoor furniture which has synthetic fabric that mold won't eat.  I don't know how comfortable it would be though.

Mold does need something to eat so if your place is really dusty that can provide a great food source for mold.

One more factor can be humidity sinks - anything in your unit that can absorb humidity.  A dehumidifier can take a while to work if you have lots of fabric / furniture that can absorb and also release moisture once it has been absorbed.  You should also ensure you don't bring additional moisture into the unit.  Use your bathroom / kitchen exhaust fans.